# jQuery-UI autocomplete to show div on auto dropdown selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, z-index

I have this jQuery UI setup.

```
$.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
      if(this.element.is("select")) {
        var self = this;
        this.original = this.element.hide();
        this.element = $("<input/>").insertAfter(this.original);
        this.options.source = function(request, response) {
          var filter = $.ui.autocomplete.filter,
            $options = self.original.find("option"),
            result = $options.map(function() {
              return $(this).html();
            });
          response(filter(result, request.term));
        };
      }
      this._super("_create");
    },
    _destroy: function() {
      this._super("_destroy");
      this.element.remove();
      this.original.show();
    }
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete();
  });
});
```

I am trying to simply trigger my modal or show my div when a autofill selection is clicked. I have tried the below, and also have tried using various other tags. Nothing is working. Any suggestions?

```
$('.ui-menu ui-widget .ui-widget-content .ui-autocomplete .ui-front').click(function(event) {
      $(".state_overlay").show();  
    // $('li.ui-menu-item').innerhtml().append.$("h2.statename"); /* edit */
});
```

*Note:* None of my jquery-UI generated selectors seems to be working with click function?

And my autocomplete markup looks like this:

```
<select id="autocomplete" class="autocomplete">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but aren't you missing the `function` keyword on the first line? Shouldn't `$.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {` be `$.widget("app.autocomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, function() {`?

Comment: No.. this is not the issues. Thanks, though.

Comment: Have you tried simply using `$('#autocomplete').click(function(etc.`?  If that works, then you know that your problem is with your jQuery selector.